# Open remote debugging mode in an already open chrome browser

Tags: selenium, puppeteer, browser-automation, chrome-debugging

I am trying to open "remote debugging mode" in an already running chrome browser.

**Here is the command I am executing:**
`chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir="C:\Users\Ideal\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data"`

But when I visit `http://127.0.0.1:9222/json/version`, nothing shows up.

However, if I close the browser and then run the same process, then `http://127.0.0.1:9222/json/version` works great.

So how can I open remote debugging mode in an already running Chrome browser?

Comment: Confused, can you clarify: the "already running chrome", did you start that with those options already? And you somehow run into a situation where to get the debug port to work, you end up having to kill it and start again the second time with those same options? Or you are trying to connect to the "already running chrome" that was started without those options?

Comment: "Or you are trying to connect to the "already running chrome" that was started without those options?" That seems to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Opening `remote debugging` mode in an already running `Chrome browser` is not directly supported by default, as the `--remote-debugging-port` flag is typically used to enable `remote debugging` during Chrome's startup. Once Chrome is running, changing this flag will not take effect.

You can  try creating a new `user profile` on the fly and then use  that profile to run Chrome with `remote debugging enabled`

```
xcopy "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default" C:\TempProfile /E /I /H /C /K /O /X

"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir="C:\TempProfile"
```